# ReleaseHandleFailed Exception

Tags: .net

I have just got the following bloody MDA exception on a rather simple little program:

> A SafeHandle or CriticalHandle of type
>   'Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeCapiHashHandle'
>   failed to properly release the handle
>   with value 0x004E48C0. This usually
>   indicates that the handle was released
>   incorrectly via another means (such as
>   extracting the handle using
>   DangerousGetHandle and closing it
>   directly or building another
>   SafeHandle around it.)

I have never seen anything like this.  My program code is:

```
public partial class SmsEditorForm : Form
{
    public SmsEditorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SmsEditorForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        using (var ents = new TemplateEntities())
        {
            templateCombo.DataSource = ents.NotificationTemplates.OrderBy(nt => nt.TemplateName).ToList();
            jobCardCombo.DataSource = ents.JobCards.Where(jc => !jc.JobDeleted && !jc.Archived).ToList();
        }
    }

    private void smsText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        charCountLabel.Text = smsText.Text.Trim().Length.ToString();
    }

    private void templateCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var ents = new TemplateEntities())
        {
            smsText.Text = ents.NotificationTemplates.Single(nt => nt.TemplateId == (int) templateCombo.SelectedValue).ExternalRecipientSms;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a problem in your SMS library. In particular, whatever part of the code uses `SafeCapiHashHandle` (this is an encryption handle, so, e.g., using a web service over SSL would cause this).

Comment: No it isn't.  The SMS service is a web service, and if I click Continue on the error dialogue, it continues and sends the SMS perfectly.